# Create the sql query to get a single LATEST value for EACH unit_id

Tags: mysql

I am working on the project and one of the things that I need to do, is to select some data

table:

```
id | unit_id | data1 | data2 | data 3 | data4 | TimeStamp

1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2012-10-18 18:17:42

2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2012-10-18 18:18:42

3 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 2012-10-20 18:19:42 

4 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 4 | 2012-10-21 18:20:42 

5 | 1 | 5 | 8 | 8 | 2012-10-22 18:21:42 

6 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2012-10-18 18:17:42 

7 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2012-10-19 18:18:42 

8 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 2012-10-20 18:19:42 

9 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 6 | 2012-10-21 18:20:42
```

and what I need, is to get `Single LATEST value for EACH unit_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will group the records by unit_id and identifies the one with latest timestamp, joins those results with the same table and selects the record with the unit_id and timestamp values.

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    MyTable a
    JOIN (SELECT 
              unit_id, 
              MAX(TimeStamp) 'TimeStamp' 
          FROM 
              MyTable 
          GROUP BY unit_id
         ) as b
    ON a.unit_id = b.unit_id AND a.Timestamp = b.TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 2):

By using GROUP BY clause, like

```
SELECT 
    unit_id, max(TimeStamp)
FROM 
    table3
GROUP BY 
    unit_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT unit_id , max(tstamp) 
FROM   t 
GROUP BY unit_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(timestamp),unit_id FROM table GROUP BY unit_id
```